# How to create multiple AWS IAM roles at once using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

So I know I can do this by just doing the resource block over and over again until I write them all out, but it seems kind of redundant. Now I'm just trying to get the roles created before attaching the policies to the roles. I looked on here and throughout the web and I couldn't find anything that seemed to do it. I looked at the aws_iam_role module source code but I didn't see how they did it for multiple roles. Any assistance would be appreciated.

example code of what I do now.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test1" {
    name = "role1"
    assume_role_policy = file("${path.module}/json_files/assume_role.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "test2" {
    name = "role2"
    assume_role_policy = file("${path.module}/json_files/assume_role.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "test3" {
    name = "role3"
    assume_role_policy = file("${path.module}/json_files/assume_role.json")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either use [count](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count) or [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each):

**with count**:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test" {
    count = 3
    name = "role${each.index}"
    assume_role_policy = file("${path.module}/json_files/assume_role.json")
}
```

**with for_each**:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test" {
    for_each = toset(["1", "2", "3"])
    name = "role${each.key}"
    assume_role_policy = file("${path.module}/json_files/assume_role.json")
}
```

Comment: That seems a lot cleaner than what I did. I also modulized it with a 
type = map(map(list(string)))